Last Data Dump is completely missing ContentLicense for Comments
I noticed that in the latest data dump, the Comments.xml files do not provide a ContentLicense for any of the rows, even though it is available in SEDE.
Here is an example of looking at the first few records in the tezos.meta site (just as an example):

As you can see, the data dump on the right does not have the ContentLicense attribute anywhere.

The ContentLicense column was also present in both the December 2023 and March 2024 data dumps, the latter prior to the changes to how the data dump was generated. The bug was likely introduced alongside whatever changes were made to the generation process

Which data dump are you talking about exactly? The March 2024 one?

@CesarM The April data dumps have the issue described in the question. All of the data dumps have the issue described in my answer.

@ThomasOwens if all the dumps have the issue you describe then even the "period to cure the violation" defined by ver 4.0 has probably been over 6-8 something ago.

@SPArcheon-onstrike 4.0 gives 30 days from the discovery. So the violation of the data dump was discovered on 31 July. The violation in the API was discovered today, 2 August. And there are also questions about commercial offerings that I can't see that were raised today, 2 August. Although 2.5 and 3.0 have no period to cure the violation - it's immediate. However, it can exist on express reinstatement. So if it does automatically terminate, I can choose to reinstate it. My understanding is that I can also waive that and opt not to do anything if I'm satisfied with the remediation.

oh, so it starts counting from the discovery date. Thanks for the explanation @ThomasOwens

We've added back the ContentLicense column to the Comments.xml file, so this shouldn't be an issue going forward.
As for Thomas' answer, we've looked into it. While the license.txt file has contained a link to CC-BY-SA 3.0, and we included a link to CC-BY-SA 4.0 on the Internet Archive page (you can download the license.txt file on that same page). We decided to make it more explicitly accessible by adding the links to the XML files wrapped in a comment. Going forward you'll see this in the XML files:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  ContentLicense

  CC BY-SA 2.5 - Url: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/
  CC BY-SA 3.0 - Url: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
  CC BY-SA 4.0 - Url: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
-->
<posthistory>
  <row Id="...>
</posthistory>

This should fix both the issue in the question as well as the one raised on Thomas' original answer. As for the API, I'll also look into it and edit this answer when I have an update.

Re: the code change from  to a XML comment (the edits in this answer). It was pointed out by folks that the proposed format was an invalid XML and would break parsers and not be read properly. We changed it to be wrapped in a XML comment to avoid that issue.

There is an even bigger problem here, and one that extends beyond the comment data's ContentLicense field.
Content on Stack Exchange sites is licensed under one of three CC BY-SA licenses, depending on when it was posted. All three licenses require including either a copy of or a URI for the license. In 2.5 and 3.0, this requirement is stated in 4(a). In 4.0, this requirement is Section 3(a)(1)(A)(v). In 4.0, Section 3(a)(2) does say that the conditions may be satisfied "in any reasonable manner based on the medium, means, and context" in which the content is shared, but given the medium and means, providing a URI is not unreasonable.
When any of the ContentLicense fields are populated, the field only contains a short name for the license ("CC BY-SA 4.0", "CC BY-SA 3.0", "CC BY-SA 2.5"). To be compliant, the field should contain a URI. The URI should probably be the canonical URL, so one of https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/ or https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/ https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/.
There may be other ways to satisfy this requirement. Creative Commons provides all three licenses in plain text as well as RDF/XML files. There may be ways to distribute these licenses as part of the data dump. However, this does seem unnecessarily verbose. Putting the URI into the readme.txt that explains the fields may also satisfy the letter of the requirements. As long as there are clear and explicit URIs to all three versions and clarity on how to go from the ContentLicense field to the full text of the license, I believe the requirements would be met.
I should also note that this same issue applies to the API. The API's content_license field is also one of CC BY-SA 4.0, CC BY-SA 3.0, or CC BY-SA 2.5 depending on the date the content was posted or last edited. I don't see anything in the API or in the API documentation that provides the required URIs for content licensed using 2.5 or 3.0 and I would suspect that it would be reasonable to expect the URI for 4.0 given the medium and means of transmitting the content. It may be worth questioning whether the OverflowAPI product suffers from a similar product, delivering improperly marked content to downstream users.
However, something else that I've noticed is that the license for the data dump is only at the top level. The individual 7z files for the sites do not contain any information about the license of the data dump as a whole. Although one could argue that, in the current scheme, the data dump is the set of 7z files, this argument may not hold after the changes to the data dump where users must request a download individually.
I'd also point out that this could be a good opportunity to update the license of the data dump. The data dump is currently licensed CC BY-SA 3.0. The collection could be licensed CC BY-SA 4.0 instead. Creative Commons typically recommends using later versions of the license where possible.

"To be compliant, the field should contain a URI." I don't think this is actually necessary, if all the URIs are provided in license.txt. If there were a License table containing all necessary information, and the comment field contained FOREIGN KEY references to it, I'd think that'd be fine too. The work as a whole would contain sufficient attribution.

I do agree that putting the URIs in a readme or license file may be sufficient. I don't like it as much, but I think it satisfies the letter of the requirements. As long as those files are part of the distribution. Changing to the per-site instead of the set of all sites would require putting the license and readme files in different places.

@testing-for-ya But what if Stack Exchange goes down? Then you need the dump to tell you how to read the dump.

@wizzwizz4 just FYI, the license.txt file only links to CC BY-SA 3.0, so the requirement is not satisfied even from that aspect.

Just wondering.... with all the ongoing discussion about the company granting itself a secondary license to the content in the site ToS, did they ever claim to be distributing the dumps under CC BY-SA? Could they be implicitly using their secondary license instead?

@SPArcheon-onstrike If there is a secondary license or not, it doesn't matter. The Terms of Service do state that "the Creative Commons Data Dump is licensed under the CC BY-SA license". The data dump may be a collection or compilation, which means that it can be licensed however the company wants. They could release the data dump CC BY-NC-SA or even all rights reserved. However, the individual works in the dump will remain under some version of CC BY-SA, unless or until the ToS changes the licenses we grant SE upon posting content and it would only affect work posted after that change.

@SPArcheon-onstrike The secondary license also doesn't give the SE the right to relicense or sublicense. So if they did distribute (or export or display) under this license and not CC BY-SA, the recipient wouldn't get any rights to copy, distribute, display, etc. For our content to be useful and usable by downstream recipients, it must be distributed under the CC BY-SA license.

@ThomasOwens If I get your post right, then the (current?) format of the dump actually doesn't fulfill the requirements of the   CC BY-SA license. If there was a claim that the dump is indeed distributed under CC BY-SA, then is this an actual violation??

@SPArcheon-onstrike There is the license of the data dump and the license of content. The license of the dump doesn't matter at all in this case. It could be all rights reserved and this would still be an issue. Every work distributed under any CC license must have a URI back to the license or the full text of the license. There is no URI back to the license associated with the questions, answers, and comments in the data dump.

@ThomasOwens isn't that my point? If the dump content is distributed under CC then it must follow the CC guidance and the (current?) format doesn't fulfill those requirement. But if the dump is distributed under the secondary license Stack seems to have then they are free to choose any format, and the ContentLicense column would be just a metadata they choose to provide for clarity sake that doesn't strictly have to follow any guidance. The "record" in the dump would be licensed under Stack own license, the fact that it is also available elsewhere as CC would not matter imho

@SPArcheon-onstrike If you're proposing SE to release our content under the secondary license from the ToS (assuming that one exists), that would also fix this issue. SE would need to remove the implication that the content is available CC BY-SA by removing the ContentLicense column and updating any other documentation with the dump. But I'm honestly not sure what it would mean to have the rights to share and adapt the compilation but have no rights to any of the works within the compilation. Unless the use was protected by fair use, I think that scheme would make the data dump useless.

@ThomasOwens No, I am just wondering if SE already violated the CC license by releasing the data dump in its current format. Obviously this would require that a) the issue you pointed out is big enough to be a violation and b) that the dump was distributed under CC and SE can not claim it was distributed under their secondary license instead. To be clear, it is not like I am planning to do anything with this, I was simply wondering if the catastrophic failure scenario depicted in another post  that would actually allow users to retract their licensing to SE isn't actually closer than we think.

@SPArcheon-onstrike Yes. This is a violation. If they are resharing under the CC BY-SA license that we, as contributors, give SE, then SE must pass along that license to downstream recipients via a URI to the license or the full text of the license. Based on the content of the dump, they are indeed trying to reshare it under the CC BY-SA license. 2.5 and 3.0 are terminated automatically upon breach. 4.0 has a period to cure the violations. Anyone would have to consult a lawyer to determine next steps.

@testing-for-ya there's a feeling that the lessons of the strikes weren't learnt. Or perhaps the wrong lessons were learnt. I think its less the 'dump' than the conduct of the company over the last decade or so. The community is quite reactive, but there's reasons for that.
